# Relation between reciprocal vector and gradient of a plane $(hkl)$

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Suppose we have a unit cell with lattice vector $\vec a_1,\;\vec a_2,\;and\;\vec a_3$ (crystallographic axes)
Consider $(hkl)$ plane. This plane makes an intercept of $\frac{1}{h}$ unit along $\vec a_1$, $\frac{1}{k}$ unit along $\vec a_2$, and $\frac{1}{l}$ unit along $\vec a_3$.
Equation of plane is $hx+ky+lz=D$
From this we can see that $\vec v = h\hat x+k\hat y+l\hat z$ is perpendicular to $(hkl)$ plane. (Here $\hat x,\;\hat y,\;\hat z$ are unit vector along orthogonal axes, not crystallographic axes)
Suppose $\vec b_1,\;\vec b_2,\;and\;\vec b_3$ are the reciprocal lattice vector of the given unit cell. We know that $\vec u=h\vec b_1+k\vec b_2+l\vec b_3$ is also perpendicular to $(hkl)$.
Also for a given plane there is only one vector which is perpendicular to it (upto unit length).
In general $\vec b_1\neq\hat x,\;\vec b_2\neq\hat y,\;and\;\vec b_3\neq\hat z$ (both in magnitude and direction)

But we get that both $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are perpendicular to $(hkl)$. But $\vec u\neq\vec v$. Doesn't that lead to contradiction?

Comment: I believe that "Equation of plane $hx+ky+lz=D$" is false, i.e, that is not the equation describing the $(hkl)$ plane.  Why do you think this is true?

Comment: It is given in https://dictionary.iucr.org/Miller_indices (above Fig-1)

Comment: Oh I see: except: look at the picture. $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not meant to indicate Cartesian coordinates. Rather, they are coordinates with respect to the primitive lattice vectors! So it's $\vec{v} = h\hat{x} + k\hat{y} + l\hat{z}$ that is wrong, because what it should really be (I think) is $\vec{v} = h\vec{a}_1 + k\vec{a}_2 + l\vec{a}_3$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still have a doubt. If $\vec v = h\vec a_1+k\vec a_2+ l\vec a_3$ which is perpendicular to the plane $(hkl)$. But still $\vec v\neq \vec u$ where $\vec u = h\vec b_1+k\vec b_2+l\vec b_3$ (reciprocal lattice vector).